# Can't add lightning:progressStep in lightning:progressIndicator using aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, platform-bug, winter18

With the Winter'18 new Lightning Base components I tried to create a `lightning:progressIndicator` with `lightning:progressStep` dynamically using  an `aura:iteration`:

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="path" type="CustomPath" />

    <lightning:progressIndicator type="path">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.path.steps}" var="step">
            <lightning:progressStep label="{!step.label}" value="{!stage.id}"/>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:progressIndicator>
</aura:component>
```

with all the path info defined in an Apex object and passed into the component:

```
public class CustomPath {

    @AuraEnabled
    public List<Step> step { get; private set; }    
    ...
}

public class Step {
    @AuraEnabled
    public Id id { get; private set; }

    @AuraEnabled
    public String label { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

The page throws strange errors like:

> Uncaught Action failed: aura:iteration$controller$itemsChange [Cannot
>   read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined]

[image]

Comment: How are you passing the `stages` array? Is this a nested component?

Comment: I am passing in a Custom Apex object. I updated the question code.

Comment: We may need this [feature](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TuFUQA0) which is not yet available as of Spring '18.

Answer (score 5):

I've been playing around and it seems that its a bit buggy.
From my point of view, it doesn't like to get the body rendered dynamically while updating the currentStep.
The following code is a work-around that works, in case no-one else give another idea...

Component

```xml
<aura:attribute name="stage" type="Map" default="{id:'id2', label:'Label 2'}" />
<aura:attribute name="progressIndicator" type="Aura.Component" />
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />
<br/><br/><br/><br/>

{!v.progressIndicator}

<ui:button press="{!c.doChangeStage}" label="Button"/>
```

Controller

```js
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        // assume this is what you get from the server call
        var stepsData = [
            {id:'id1',label:'Label 1'},
            {id:'id2',label:'Label 2'},
            {id:'id3',label:'Label 3'},
            {id:'id4',label:'Label 4'}];

        // List of components to create, starting with the father itself
        var stepsPreComponents = [[
            "lightning:progressIndicator",
            {
                "currentStep" : component.getReference('v.stage.id')
            }
        ]];

        // Add the steps
        for (var index in stepsData) {
            var step = stepsData[index];
            stepsPreComponents.push([
                "lightning:progressStep",
                {
                    "label":step.label,
                    "value":step.id
                }
            ]);
        }

        $A.createComponents(
            stepsPreComponents,
            function(components, status, errorMessage){
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    // Remove the father
                    var progressIndicator = components.shift();
                    // Add the rest to the father
                    progressIndicator.set('v.body',components);
                    // Assign it to the view Attribute
                    component.set('v.progressIndicator',progressIndicator);
                } else {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            }
        );
    }, 

    doChangeStage : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.stage.id', 'id4');
    }
})
```

Comment: This solution is not nice, but works, I would be glad to have a better solution if anyone finds one...

Comment: This can be a work around. But still we may need this [feature](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TuFUQA0) which is not yet available as of Spring '18.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either your sample code is incomplete, or you are missing some variables - the main issue seems to be path.currentStep isn't definied in your apex class.

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="path" type="CustomPath" />

// There isn't anything in your controller that maps to v.path.currentStep. 
// When the component tries to parse it, it can't read the 'Id' because there is not variable called 'currentSetup', so it results in a 'hasOwnProperty' error
<lightning:progressIndicator currentStep="{!v.path.currentStep.id}"> 
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.path.steps}" var="step">
        <lightning:progressStep label="{!step.label}" value="{!stage.id}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:progressIndicator>
```

To verify that this is correct, try temporarily removing the currentStep attribute on the `lightning:progressIndicator` and see if it then loads successfully

Comment: Seems to not be connected to current step. I removed it and nothing changed