# lightning:progressIndicator fails to render with aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am attempting to use the new `lightning:progressIndicator` component to display a process. If I hardcode the steps like below, things render fine:

```
<lightning:progressIndicator type="path">
  <lightning:progressStep label="First" value="0"/>
  <lightning:progressStep label="Second" value="1"/>
  <lightning:progressStep label="Third" value="2"/>
</lightning:progressIndicator>
```

However, because I am making a more complex app my steps are going to be dynamic. Trying to use a simple `aura:iteration` causes the path to render as empty.

```
<lightning:progressIndicator type="path">
  <aura:iteration items="First,Second,Third" var="label" indexVar="labelNum">
    <lightning:progressStep label="{!label}" value="{!labelNum}"/>
  </aura:iteration>
</lightning:progressIndicator>
```

Am I missing something here? I can't imagine that using an iteration is simply not supported for this component.

Comment: yes this is bit buggy. this is alternative https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/196345/17316

Comment: That approach seems like such a significant effort in each place we want to use the progress indicator that I am thinking it might be less work to just implement my own.

Comment: I face the same problem with the iteration, @dsharrison - did you find any good solution?

Comment: We may need this [feature](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TuFUQA0) which is not yet available as of Spring '18.

Answer (score 1):

as of 03/08/2018, still does not work with the aura:iteration

```
<lightning:progressIndicator type="base" title="Job Progress"   >
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.jobScanStatusPicklist}" var="item" >
    <lightning:progressStep label="{!item.label}" value="{!item.label}"/>
 </aura:iteration>
</lightning:progressIndicator>
```

too bad -(