# lightning:progressIndicator is not working in aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I created progressIndicator using static value with iteration and without iteration.

Working fine, When progressIndicator using without iteration, but with iteration is not rendered like progressIndicator without iteration

here is my code. Any advice / suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

**ProgressIndicator.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

<aura:attribute name="picklistValues" type="List" access="public"/>
<aura:attribute name="currentValue" type="String" default="Closed" access="public"/>


<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

Without iteration : <br/>

<lightning:progressIndicator currentStep="{!v.currentValue}" type="path"  variant="base" class="slds-p-around_small">
    <lightning:progressStep label="Contacted" value="Contacted"/>
    <lightning:progressStep label="Open" value="Open"/>
    <lightning:progressStep label="Unqualified" value="Unqualified"/>
    <lightning:progressStep label="Nurturing" value="Nurturing"/>
    <lightning:progressStep label="Closed" value="Closed"/>
</lightning:progressIndicator>

With iteration : <br/> 

<lightning:progressIndicator currentStep="{!v.currentValue}" type="path" variant="base" class="slds-p-around_small">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.picklistValues}" var="pickValue">
        <lightning:progressStep label="{!pickValue}" value="{!pickValue}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:progressIndicator>

    </aura:component>
```

**ProgressIndicatorController.js**

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var picklistValues = ["Contacted ",
                              "Open",
                              "Unqualified",
                              "Nurturing",
                              "Closed"
                             ];
        cmp.set("v.picklistValues", picklistValues);
    }
})
```

[image: Here Screen attached]

Comment: can you share your js code, how you can setting value in attribute picklistValues?

Comment: I tried this but aura:iteration is not working inside progress bar. it can be a bug in Lightning:progressIndicator.

Comment: @ManjotSingh I shared my js code. Yes, It can be a bug in Lightning:progressIndicator. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a known bug with the lightning platform.

A solution would be to create **lightning:progressIndicator** component dynamically in Javascript.

Sample Pseudo Code to create components in Javascript.

```
$A.createComponents(
            stepsPreComponents,
            function(components, status, errorMessage){
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    // Remove the father
                    var progressIndicator = components.shift();
                    // Add the rest to the father
                    progressIndicator.set('v.body',components);
                    // Assign it to the view Attribute
                    component.set('v.progressIndicator',progressIndicator);
                } else {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            }
        );
```

Detailed Example here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/196345/19118

Comment: Do you have a link to the known issue?  Do we need to create one

Comment: Hi @EricSSH, I had it bookmarked, which I can't find it right now :(

Comment: All I can find is this https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TuFUQA0..